# Ggplot subset data functions and dplyr

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

When doing data analysis, we often use dplyr to modify the dataframe further in specific `geom`s. This allows us to change the default dataframe of a ggplot later, and have everything still work.

```
template <- ggplot(db, aes(x=time, y=value)) + 
     geom_line(data=function(db){db %>% filter(event=="Bla")}) + 
     geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=low, ymax=up))
ggsave( template, "global.png" )
for(i in unique(db$simulation)) 
     ggsave( template %+% subset(db, simulation==i), paste0(i, ".png")
```

Is there a nicer/shorter way to specify the `filter` command, e.g. using some magical `.`?

*EDIT*
To clarify some of the comments: By using `geom_line(data = db %>% filter(event=="Bla"))`, the layer would not be updated when I change the default dataframe later using `%+%`. I am really aiming to use the `data` argument of geom_* as a function.

Comment: `geom_line(data = filter(db, event=="Bla"))` or `geom_line(data = db %>% filter(event=="Bla"))`

Comment: You can also declare db before `ggplot` : `db %>% ggplot(., aes(x=time, y = value)) + geom_line(filter(., event == "Bla")) [...]`.

Comment: And replace `for` with `by`: `by(db, db$simulation, function(subdf) { i <- subdf$simulation[[1]]; ggsave(template %+% subdf, paste0(i, ".png")) })`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upon reading the documentation of `%>%` better, I have found the solution:

> **Using the dot-place holder as lhs**
>       When the dot is used as lhs, the result will be a functional sequence, i.e. a function which applies the entire chain of right-hand sides in turn to its input. See the examples.

Therefore, the nicest way to formulate the above example, incorporating the suggestions from above as well:

```
db <- diamonds
template <- ggplot(db, aes(x=carat, y=price, color=cut)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(data=. %>% filter(color=="J")) +
  labs(caption="Smooths only for J color")
ggsave( template, "global.png" )
db %>% group_by(cut) %>% do(
  ggsave( paste0(.$cut[1], ".png"), plot=template %+% .)
)
```